# Почему не понимает Sql запрос?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
2020-03-17 16:35:02.936 ERROR 4800 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL [select cancelledc0_.ID as id1_0_, cancelledc0_.PERSON_FULL_NAME as person_f2_0_, cancelledc0_.LAWYER_ID as lawyer_i3_0_, (select l.version from lawyers l where l.id = cancelledc0_.lawyer_id) as formula1_ from COMMON_BASE_DOC cancelledc0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query] with root cause

org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: multiple rows in singleton select
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2103) ~[jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar:2.2.15-JDK_1.8 (build: tag=v2.2.15 date=201904061030)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2053) ~[jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar:2.2.15-JDK_1.8 (build: tag=v2.2.15 date=201904061030)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlFetch(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1318) ~[jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar:2.2.15-JDK_1.8 (build: tag=v2.2.15 date=201904061030)]
```

```
Tue Mar 17 15:57:36 MSK 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute query; SQL [select cancelledc0_.ID as id1_0_, cancelledc0_.PERSON_FULL_NAME as person_f2_0_, cancelledc0_.LAWYER_ID as lawyer_i3_0_, (select l.version from lawyers l where l.id = cancelledc0_.lawyer_id) as formula1_ from COMMON_BASE_DOC cancelledc0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
```

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMON_BASE_DOC")
public class CancelledCertificates{

    public CancelledCertificates() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "REG_CAPTION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String reg_caption;
    @Column(name = "REG_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String reg_code;

    @Formula("(select l.version fromlawyers l, common_base_doc cbd, where l.id = cbd.lawyer_id and cbd.id = id)")

    private Integer version;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFio() {
        return fio;
    }

    public void setFio(String fio) {
        this.fio = fio;
    }

    public Long getLawyer_id() {
        return lawyer_id;
    }

    public void setLawyer_id(Long lawyer_id) {
        this.lawyer_id = lawyer_id;
    }

    public Integer getIs_not_returned() {
        return is_not_returned;
    }

    public void setIs_not_returned(Integer is_not_returned) {
        this.is_not_returned = is_not_returned;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Hibernate не понимает sql запрос, хотя в редакторе запрос выполняется.

```
@Formula("(select l.version from lawyers l, common_base_doc cbd" +
          "where l.id = cbd.lawyer_id and cbd.id = id)")
 private Integer version;
```

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not prepare statement; SQL [select cancelledc0_.ID as id1_0_, cancelledc0_.PERSON_FULL_NAME as person_f2_0_, cancelledc0_.LAWYER_ID as lawyer_i3_0_, (select lic.is_not_returned from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id and common_base_doc.id = cancelledc0_.id) as formula1_, (select l.version from LAWYER_IDENT ITY_CARD cancelledc0_.lic, lawyers l, common_base_doc cbd, where l.id = cbd.lawyer_id and lic.id = cbd.id and cbd.id = cancelledc0_.id) as formula2_ from COMMON_BASE_DOC cancelledc0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Comment: 1) Нет пробела  между алиасом и WHERE. 2) Лишние скобки вокруг текста запроса.

Comment: @Formula("select l.version from lawyers l, common_base_doc cbd where l.id = cbd.lawyer_id and cbd.id = id") тоже не работает

Comment: из какой таблицы делается запрос? добавьте класс в вопрос.

Comment: Вот и класс добавлен)

Comment: Запрос должен быть вида `@Formula("select l.version from lawyers l where l.id = lawyer_id")`. В классе вижу метод getLawyer_id, но не вижу поля для него((

Comment: Не работает и так.

Comment: @Formula("(select l.version from lawyers l where l.id = lawyer_id)")
  private Integer version;

Comment: В ошибке указан запрос, попробуйте его выполнить. hibernate жалуется на неправильный синтаксис, нужно привести его к правильному. В запросе из ошибки не тот запрос, который указан в этом вопросе. Добавьте ошибку, которая возникает и указание, что работает не так.

Comment: Ошибка добавлена)

Comment: в новой ошибке уже сформирован правильный запрос, он выполняется напрямую в БД? Есть подозрения на названия колонок и таблиц (только большие буквы)

Comment: select l.version from lawyers l, common_base_doc cbd where l.id = cbd.lawyer_id;

Comment: Так выполняется

Comment: а запрос из ошибки?

Comment: @Formula("(select l.version from lawyers l where l.id = lawyer_id)") private Integer version; вот он

Comment: запрос из ошибки: `SELECT cancelledc0_.ID                                                       AS id1_0_,
       cancelledc0_.PERSON_FULL_NAME                                         AS person_f2_0_,
       cancelledc0_.LAWYER_ID                                                AS lawyer_i3_0_,
       (SELECT l.version FROM lawyers l WHERE l.id = cancelledc0_.lawyer_id) AS formula1_
FROM COMMON_BASE_DOC cancelledc0` он выполняется напрямую в БД?

Comment: Нет не выполняется. Выполняется так:

Comment: select l.version from lawyers l, common_base_doc cbd where l.id = cbd.lawyer_id;

Comment: БД пишет ошибку, почему не выполняется?

Comment: @Akina как выполнить запрос `SELECT cancelledc0_.ID AS id1_0_, cancelledc0_.PERSON_FULL_NAME AS person_f2_0_, cancelledc0_.LAWYER_ID AS lawyer_i3_0_, (SELECT l.version FROM lawyers l WHERE l.id = cancelledc0_.lawyer_id) AS formula1_ FROM COMMON_BASE_DOC cancelledc0` на `firebirdsql`? ругается `multiple rows in singleton select`